# HCE support for NXP PN544 Controller

Tags: android, nfc, hce

I have been trying to implement HCE on NXP PN544 but i am not able to succeed in achieving it. While my R&D i didn't find any documentation which clearly states that whether this chip support HCE or not?

Can any one help me if NXP PN544 Controller chipset has support for Host Card (HC) emulation? and if any documentation on same will be really of great help.

Comment: Are you targeting any specific platform (e.g. Android)?

Comment: Yes, I am targeting it for Android - Kitkat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the PN544 supports host card emulation. CyanogenMod versions from 9.1 to 10.2(?) contain an implementation of a HCE mode for devices that have a PN544 NFC controller chip (see this [commit](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Nfc/commit/d41edfd794d4d0fedd91d561114308f0d5f83878) and this [commit](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_external_libnfc-nxp/commit/34f13082c2e78d1770e98b4ed61f446beeb03d88) to the CyanogenMod source repositories, and see [Nikolay's blog](http://nelenkov.blogspot.co.at/2012/10/emulating-pki-smart-card-with-cm91.html) for a usage example). However, this mode is different from the current (Android 4.4+) HCE API. Moreover, support for the CyanogenMod specific HCE was dropped in favor of Android HCE starting with CM version 11.

Most devices that contain a PN544 do not currently support Android HCE. *I have no confirmation for this, so this is my personal **guess**:* As far as I understand it, the PN544 can be put in HCE mode, but it does not support the dynamic routing mechanism that permits the HCE mode to co-exist (i.e. be enabled at the same time) as a secure element. Consequently, it would be a decision to *either* enable HCE mode *or* use a secure element on such devices.

Answer (score 2):

As Michael mentioned, PN544 hardware does have support for host card emulation, however currently (mid 2014), only closed source drivers shipped in stock ROMs of KitKat based devices have this capability (e.g. HTC One m8).

See the following xda-developers thread for current findings and progress in enabling this support in AOSP ROMs:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2573842